# mocha with redux: expected undefined to equal true

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, react-intl

I'm trying to wrote test for my react component which using redux and react-intl:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Navbar from 'Navbar';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import messages from '../src/l10n/en.json'
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const store = mockStore({})


describe('<Navbar />', () => {

  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale={ "en" } messages={ messages }>
          <Navbar />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(Navbar.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

But I got this result:

```
  <Navbar />
    1) calls componentDidMount


  0 passing (73ms)
  1 failing

  1) <Navbar /> calls componentDidMount:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to equal true
```

Can some one give me an advise how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because, `componentDidMount` is not spy'ed in the test. You could use `sinon` to do fix this issue. For instance,

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Navbar from 'Navbar';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import messages from '../src/l10n/en.json'
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'
import { spy } from 'sinon';

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const store = mockStore({})


describe('<Navbar />', () => {
  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    spy(Navbar.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale={ "en" } messages={ messages }>
          <Navbar />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(Navbar.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

On a side note:-  If you want to use `react-intl` in tests, I would suggest to use helper functions as described [here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#helper-function-1)

Comment: I tried to use helper with react component without redux:
https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/95b4222c77d2dad9255cab83bc99351d



But I got this an error:
`
1) <NotFound /> have text:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined
`

Comment: it's working without helpers
https://gist.github.com/pustovalov/2d4932a898156b973c38efd86025cd4b

Comment: Hmm that was a suggestion for a best practice. That error most probably because of react-intl issues. Would you be able to accept this answer?